# How can I find the max "income" from every "product" in every "province"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

| PRODUCT | PROVINCE | INCOME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Seville | 13.2 |
| Melon | Almeria | 3.6 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    PRODUCT,
    PROVINCE,
    MAX(TOTAL)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            PRODUCT,
            PROVINCE,
            SUM(INCOME) TOTAL
        FROM  SALES
        GROUP BY  PRODUCT,PROVINCE
    )
GROUP BY PRODUCT,PROVINCE;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: How is the MAX income different than the TOTAL income?  Is there another factor you've left out, like Year or something?

Comment: Your question as it stands makes no sense, by grouping and aggregating in your sub-query you already have 1 row per product/province, `max` will not change anything.

Comment: Your query should result in `Error: ER_DERIVED_MUST_HAVE_ALIAS: Every derived table must have its own alias`. To resolve you need to add an alias of your select. `SELECT  s.PRODUCT,  s.PROVINCE, MAX(s.TOTAL) FROM (SELECT ... ) AS s ...`.  Additionally how are you expecting the `SUM` of the grouping differ from the `MAX`? Since `SUM` will only have a single value for the declared groupings of `PRODUCT, PROVINCE`, so there would be no `MAX` to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT PRODUCTO, PROVINCIA
FROM VENTAS 
WHERE RECAUDACION IN (SELECT MAX(RECAUDACION)
FROM VENTAS
GROUP BY PROVINCIA)
GROUP BY PROVINCIA, PRODUCTO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `sum` the `income`s. You only need the `max` of that `income` grouped by
the `product` and the `province`:

```sql
SELECT   product, province, MAX(income)
FROM     sales
GROUP BY product, province
```